# Filter property from multiple objects in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I have an array of objects that look like this

```
const data = [
    {id: 1, locale: 'en'},
    {id: 2, locale: 'nl'}
]
```

Now I'm trying to **filter out the locale property in every item in the array** (not delete it for good, just filter it out this once), so my data would ideally resemble this:

```
const data = [
    {id: 1},
    {id: 2}
]
```

#### I've tried

- Using a map function to spread out the properties, but I'm stuck as to how to continue with this.

  ```
  this.translations.map(translation => {
      return { ...translation }
  })
  ```

Comment: Actually I want to EXCLUDE, the other values. Since there might be more values

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [parameter destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) to extract the `locale` and keep the other ones:

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1, locale: 'en'},
    {id: 2, locale: 'nl'}
]

const withoutLocale = data.map(({locale, ...rest}) => rest)

console.log(withoutLocale)
```

Comment: this is a perfect solution. +1

Answer (score 0):

Do like this `({key:value})` with return map

**For your case**

```
this.translations.map(translation => {
    return ({['id']:translation.id })
})
```

**Working example**

```js
const data = [{id: 1, locale: 'en'},{id: 2, locale: 'nl'}];

var res = data.map(a=> ({['id']:a.id}));
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way to that using `map()` `reduce()` `filter()`. This method is for dynamic keys to be filtered out.

```js
const data = [
    {id: 1, locale: 'en'},
    {id: 2, locale: 'nl'}
]
let filter = ['locale']
function removeKeys(keys,arr){
  return data.map(x => Object.keys(x).filter(b => !keys.includes(b)).reduce((ac,a) => ({...ac,[a]:x[a]}),{}))
}

console.log(removeKeys(filter,data));
```